# MongoDB process size in task manager

Tags: windows, mongodb, caching

I have been working on MongoDB and insterted upto 1 GB data into a database collection and noticed that the process size of MongoDB shown in task manager is 25mb but overall Memory in Performance tab of task manager is getting higher as i insert data, Question is why that 1 GB is not part of Process Size shown by task manager, i know that mongodb store it on Files but yet it cache a part of that data in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB (<= 2.6) uses memory-mapped files. This means that the database asks the operating system to map the data files to a portion of *virtual* memory. The operating system then handles moving things in and out of physical memory according to what the database accesses. Your 1GB of data is mapped into virtual memory, but is likely not resident in physical memory since you have not accessed it recently. To see more detailed statistics about MongoDB's memory usage, run `db.serverStatus()` in the shell and look at the [`mem`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#mem) section. You can read a bit more about the memory-mapped storage engine in the [storage FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/).